# Subset a data.table with two joined conditions

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, subset

I would like to use data.table to collect information from the following dataset.

```
set.seed(1)
TDT <- data.table(nr= c(1:100),Group = c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("C",10),rep("D",10),rep("E",10),rep("F",10),rep("G",10),rep("H",10),rep("I",10),rep("J",10)),
                      id = c(rep(1,20),rep(2,20),rep(3,20),rep(4,20),rep(5,20)),
                      Time = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-03"), length=20, by="1 month") - 1,5),
                      norm = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                      y = sample(100,100),
                      x2 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                      x3 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                      x4 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                      x5 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2))
vars <- c("B", "C", "D")
```

I would like to get the rows for which the condition below applies:

Group is A & y >= 50 AND Any value of `var` (B, C or D) has y >= 50.

But I cannot get the syntax right. Any ideas how to implement these double conditions? Something like

```
X <- TDT[(Group=="A" & y>=50)&(Group==vars & y>=50)]
```

EDIT: I need the second condition to apply to B OR C OR D. Not AND.

Comment: What is the expected output? The attempt syntax doesn't make this clear. For example, `id` cannot equal `'A'` because it is numeric.

Comment: Sorry, you guys are right! Corrected it.

Comment: I kind of messed up the question. I edited it. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Concerning your edit: as mentioned by @IceCreamToucan the expected output would have been very helpful.

Comment: I think the edits made to the question clarified the intent of the OP. I think it should be put out of the "on hold" state...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close:

```
TDT[(Group == "A" & y >= 50) & (Group %in% vars & y >= 50), ]
```

Although a better sintax would be:

```
TDT[Group %in% c("A", vars) & y >= 50, ]
```

considering that the condition `y >= 50` has to be kept in both scenarios.

**EDIT TO EXPLAIN**

Let me explain why your code wasn't working:

Let's call `(Group == "A" & y >= 50)` condition 1. Condition 1 makes necessary that `Group` be identical to A, and that `y` be greater or equal than 50.

Condition 2, `(Group == vars & y >= 50)`, requires that `Group` is equal to **all** of the values of `vars`, namely a vector `c("B", "C", "D")` and that `y` is greater than or equal to 50. The first part will never be matched with your example, that's why I introduced `%in%`, to check that `Group` was equal to **any** of the values in `vars`.

The `&` Joining conditions 1 and 2 requires **both** conditions to hold true, and it's impossible that `Group` is simultaneously equal to both `A` and say `B`.

You wanted to check that `Group` is equal to **any** of the values in the set made of `"A"` and `vars`.

See `?'%in%'` for further details.

Comment: which results in an empty `data.table`

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to make the above apply to only 1 category of `var`?

Comment: it results in an empty data.table because of the `&` joining both conditions. There's no row whose group is both `A` and a value in `vars`. See my edit

Comment: yeah, I know :)

Comment: You might want to delete the leading parenthesis in your better "sintax"

Comment: @PavoDive I noticed I phrased my question wrong. The problem is that not all `var` should exceed 50, but one of the `var`. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please check if the proposed solution `TDT[Group %in% c("A", vars) & y >= 50, ]` works and let me know.

Comment: Since you're using `data.table` then `%chin%` can increase performance.

Answer (score 0):

`%in%` allows you to match multiple arguments, e.g.

```
TDT[Group %in% vars & y>=50]
```

Comment: This solution will leave out a case in which `Group == "A"` and `y >= 50`. There are 3 such cases in the toy data.

Comment: Ah yes, I answered before the question was edited and so I was just guessing at what Tom was asking. Your answer is the correct one :)